# Correct way to initialize a container of std::byte

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, std-byte

What is the correct way of initializing a container with predetermined std::byte values?

`std::array<std::byte, 2> arr{0x36, 0xd0}` for array results in

> Enum std::byte has not constant to represent the integer value of X

and compiler errors. Vector and initializer lists are a no-go too.

Is std::vector with std::copy and casts really the intended way of handling this?

Comment: A numeric value n can be converted to a byte value using std::byte{n}, due to C++17 relaxed enum class initialization rules.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte

Comment: OK, I know this, and it is perfectly fine for this example. But for, let's say, 20 values... it's cumbersome. Is there really no better way?

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you want to use std::byte rather than say, unsigned char?

Comment: API I have no control over. Even if I did, there is semantic correctness. We  finally have a nice standardized way of telling "these data are not numbers nor characters. They are just values to be passed/sent/whatever". This is my case exactly. Why would I not want to use it? Except the reason for this question, I mean :)

Comment: chars _are_ numbers, and I think you will find std::byte very inconvenient to use and maintain, as your  question suggests.

Comment: Yes. Of course. Everything is a number in the end. But as I was saying, there is a matter of semantics and getting the point across to other people.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Your comment surprises me. Wouldn't the logical conclusion of your comment be, that `std::byte` is useless? It's either "the way" to represent memory in C++17, or its not. I don't see much value in sometimes using it to represent memory depending on whether or not it is convenient.

Comment: @Nir I don't know enough about C++17, and neither does anyone else, because we have not had enough experience of it yet, to say if std::byte is useful or difficult to use. Lots of C++ features have proved to be A Bad Idea in retrospect. For std::byte, how does one go about interfacing it with C code (as a for instance)?

Comment: @NeilButterworth You write a generic function that calls `data` on its input, ensures that the return type is `byte*`, and casts into a `char*`. .`some_c_func(c_data(my_array));`. Pretty much analogous to `c_str`, just a free function instead. Not pretty, but there are much uglier things than that which arise when interfacing with C libraries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will have to write `std::byte{0x36}`, because there is no implicit conversion from an `int` to a `enum class`.

```
std::array<std::byte, 2> arr = {std::byte{0x36}, std::byte{0xd0}};
```

If you don't want to write `std::byte` every single time, write a helper function:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::array<std::byte, sizeof...(Ts)> make_bytes(Ts&&... args) noexcept {
    return{std::byte(std::forward<Ts>(args))...};
}

auto arr = make_bytes(0x36, 0xd0);
```

Comment: You don't really need perfect forwarding when you know everything is char/unsigned char :)

Comment: Was about to post my own answer, since I naively would have expected `std::array<std::byte, 2> arr{{0x36}, {0xd0}};` to also work(Spoiler: it doesn't). I think they really need to iron out the inconsistencies a bit more between initializer lists and aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It has everything to do with initializer lists and aggregate initialization unless I am missing something, since the moral equivalent for a non aggregate type `std::vector<std::byte> arr{{0x36}, {0xd0}};` seems to work fine.

Comment: @TimSeguine Came across your comment, and you are right. No idea what I was thinking at the time :)

Comment: Above approach did not works in msvs2019. I see the followed error: - error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::byte'

Comment: @TimSeguine: "*I think they really need to iron out the inconsistencies a bit more between initializer lists and aggregate initialization.*" Where is the inconsistency? `std::byte` is not an aggregate, so it would not use aggregate initialization. `std::byte` is not implicitly convertible from `0x36`, so using `{0x36}` to copy-list-initialize one will not work. That's not inconsistent with anything.

Comment: @NickBolas except for the fact that C++ educators (even Bjarne) like to refer to initializer lists as "uniform initialization syntax". When the brace can have multiple inconsistent meanings, so that is obviously misleading. Yeah, if I know all the rules for initialization, it is clear what should happen.  But to anyone who doesn't the differences between initializer lists and aggregate initialization seem arbitrary and mysterious. It is one of the many things that makes advanced and even intermediate C++ IMO unteachable. I have had many confused coworkers come to me because of this stuff.

Comment: @NickBolas, I just think too often we forget what these rules seem like to non-experts.

Answer (score 3):

With C++20, you can utilize `to_array` to create an array of `unsigned char` easily, then `bit_cast` it to an array of `byte`:

```cpp
auto arr = std::bit_cast<std::array<std::byte, 2>>(
    std::to_array<unsigned char>({0x36, 0xd0, /*...*/})
);
```