# How to define a static array of std::byte in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, std, std-byte

I've got this long list of bytes (as in, they don't represent chars or int).
At the moment, I can just do the following:

```
static const char myArray[] = {0xb8, 0xfe, 0x6c, 0x39, 0x23, ...}
```

What I would like is to replace `char` with `std::byte`, but the compiler complains

> a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const std::byte"

I've seen a couple of suggestions floating around, but I don't find any of them appropriate:

1. Wrap each byte in a `std::byte()` call.
   While that certainly is the easiest way to fix it, I hope we can appreciate how ridiculous that would look.
2. `static const std::byte* myByteArray= reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(myArray);`
   It's ***a*** solution, but I lose the ability to query the size (`sizeof myByteArray`) and I have to deal with an extra variable.
3. Using a variadic template function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172360/4820749)
   This solution changes the data type I was working with. And maybe I'm just not experienced enough, but I don't trust `std::array` for defining static arrays.
4. User-defined literals.
   Similar to point (1), but shorter. I can overload `_b` and apply it to every element. This still leaves me wishing for a solution where I don't have to touch every item in the list.

I was also thinking about a variadic macro that could apply the byte constructor over each item, but macros can't be recursive and I don't know enough about them in the first place.

Is there anything I left out? Let me know if there is a good solution out there.

Comment: Does `uint8_t` suffer the same?

Comment: Since a `byte` on most systems is an unsigned 8-bit integer, try using `uint8_t`.

Comment: " but I don't trust std::array for defining static arrays." why? A `std::array` is really just a c-array wrapped in a class.

Comment: `std::byte` looks nice on paper but for reasons like this, I've never actually used it.

Comment: "I don't trust std::array for defining static arrays." - Seriously? You've got to be kidding me - that is *the* way to get a static array. Use it.

Comment: what you can do with a `std::byte` c-array you can also do with a `std::array<std::byte,N>`. Saying this would "change the datatype" isnt quite correct. If you do prefer the c-array, it is `the_stdarray.data()`

Comment: Why don't you trust `std::array`? We can discuss specific concerns.

Comment: My main concern about using `std::array` was that the compiler would not optimize it the same way as it would a C array, but after looking into it, that is not the case.
This might be the best solution out of the ones I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user defined literal operator e.g. ([code link](https://godbolt.org/z/q7xYreb58)):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr std::byte operator""_b(unsigned long long int i){
    return static_cast<std::byte>(i);
}

static const std::array arr_cpp { 0xb8_b, 0xfe_b, 0x6c_b, 0x39_b, 0x23_b };

static const std::byte arr_c[] { 0xb8_b, 0xfe_b, 0x6c_b, 0x39_b, 0x23_b };

int main(){
    for(auto a : arr_cpp){
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(a) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "-----------\n";
    for(auto a : arr_c){
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(a) << "\n";
    }
   return 0; 
}
```

It doesn't really matter if you use pure c array or a wrapped c++ array - in c++ there is no constant conversion from int to std::byte or char.

Comment: what do you mean by "constant conversion"?

Comment: 0xb8 is a literal of type `int` - int's can't be implicitly converted to char/byte even if the constant value fits in the target range.
In csharp for example you could create such a byte-array with integer literals because of implicit constant conversion (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#10211-implicit-constant-expression-conversions).